# How to design class around null values from database?

Tags: c#, class-design

In my class I have these setters/getters:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public String ProjectName { get; set; }
public String ProjectType { get; set; }
public String Description { get; set; }
public String Status { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

DateTime is a non-nullable type. So, when I retrieve my data from my legacy database that I pass to the class constructor, I get an error when the StartDate is null.

How should I go about designing around this?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make any struct nullable starting with .NET 2.0.

```
 public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

Notice the `?`. Its a compiler operator to make `Nullable<DateTime>`.

When pulling it out of the reader, you can do this

```
 obj.StartDate = reader["StartDate"] as DateTime?;
```

Here is some more information on nullable types: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275471/Nullable-Types-in-Csharp-Net

Comment: @NominSim  No you do. `DateTime` is a value type.

Comment: @DanielA.White [`Nullable<T>` is also a value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), but must have some special gubbins going on to be used with `as` like that, likely the same gubbins that allow you to assign `null` to it.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - true. the compiler knows a lot about this type.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Nullable<T> is a nullable value type, whereas DateTime is a non-nullable value type. Therein lies the difference.

Comment: @NominSim That's a bit too "chicken and egg" for me :-) But I was more making reference to the fact that `as` only works with reference types by design, but `Nullable<T>` must have special case handling to work.